# Android - Table layout like gmail's attachment layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to create a table view with rows and columns dynamically so that when I delete an item from a column, all other items should rearrange automatically. I saw gmail app where the attachment layout in Compose screen behaves exactly same. How can I achieve the same in my app? I tried TableLayout but when I delete an item from a column, it leaves blank space there instead of rearranging automatically.

Comment: try `GridView` and use adapter.notifydatasetChanged() when data is deleted.

Comment: I want to add items one by one at runtime. Can I use GridView for this?

Comment: Yes..why not ? Same as `ListView`

Comment: I have a ScrollView as the root element. Putting GridView inside ScrollView can have negative impacts on my app as it is not recommended. Is there any other layout which I can use instead of GridView?